# Multilne xml file on Spring batch

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-batch

i used Spring Batch to read a database an write a xml file, but i cant find some configuration to make a multiple xml line file, i need on this way:

```
<xmlRecord><name>RecordOne</name></xmlRecord>
<xmlRecord><name>RecordTwo</name></xmlRecord>
```

each record into a line

but i only can created on this way:

```
<xmlRecord><name>RecordOne</name></xmlRecord><xmlRecord><name>RecordTwo</name></xmlRecord>
```

that is my configuration:

```
<bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="resource"
        value="file:/var/opt/result.tmp" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="userUnmarshaller" />
    <property name="overwriteOutput" value="true" />
    <property name="RootTagName" value="!-- --"/>
</bean>
```

Marshal bean configuration:

```
<bean id="userUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>my.jaxb.data.TCRMService</value>
        </list>         
    </property>
    <property name="marshallerProperties"> 
        <map>               
            <entry>
                <key><util:constant static-field="javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION"/></key>
                <value>http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema MDMDomains.xsd</value>
            </entry>
        </map>    
    </property>
</bean>
```

Someone can help me or provide me some configuration to solve my problem?

Comment: Can you attach the userMarshaller bean configuration?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski i added my userMarshal bean

Comment: Possibly same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41566545/the-xml-output-from-the-spring-batch-jaxb2marshaller-marshaller-jaxb-formatted/

Answer (score 0):

Use below unmarshaller configuration:-

```
<bean id="userUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list> your_class </list>
    </property>
    <property name="marshallerProperties">
        <map>
            <entry>
                <key>
                    <util:constant static-field="javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT" />
               </key>
              <value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

you can also do, something like below:-

```
<property name="marshallerProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="jaxb.formatted.output">
                <value type="boolean">true</value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
```

Comment: i tried your configuration, but i obtain the same result