# The XML output from the Spring Batch Jaxb2Marshaller - Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT is not working, why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am working on **Spring Batch MongoDB to XML**. I've the following two code snippet.

**First:**

```
<bean id="reportMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <value>com.mkyong.model.Report</value>
    </property>
    <property name="marshallerProperties">
        <map>
            <entry>
                <key>
                    <util:constant static-field="javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT"/>
                </key>
                <value type="boolean">true</value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Second**

```
<bean id="reportMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <value>com.mkyong.model.Report</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Both configuration is not formatting the output file. The Result is printed in a only single line of XML file. I was expecting the **First** configuration will format the result, but its not.

`JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT` The name of the property used to specify whether or not the marshalled XML data is formatted with linefeeds and indentation. But unfortunately this is not happening.

The ouput which I see in single line of xml file:

[image: output]

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <spring.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.batch.version>3.0.7.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
    <spring.data.version>1.8.4.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
    <mongodb.driver.version>3.1.1</mongodb.driver.version>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <jcl.slf4j.version>1.7.12</jcl.slf4j.version>

    <!-- Test -->
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring XML to/back object -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Batch dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Batch unit test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MongoDB database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${mongodb.driver.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${jcl.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am using following:

```
<bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:outputs/report.xml" />
    <property name="encoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
    <property name="version" value="1.0" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="reportMarshaller" />
    <property name="rootTagName" value="record" />
    <!-- TRUE means, that output file will be overwritten if exists - default is TRUE -->
    <property name="overwriteOutput" value="true" />
</bean>
```

**As per inputs from Karthik:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<record><record id="1">
    <date>01-06-2013</date>
    <impression>139237</impression>
    <clicks>40</clicks>
    <earning>220.90</earning>
  </record><record id="2">
    <date>02-06-2013</date>
    <impression>339100</impression>
    <clicks>60</clicks>
    <earning>320.88</earning>
  </record><record id="3">
    <date>03-06-2013</date>
    <impression>431436</impression>
    <clicks>76</clicks>
    <earning>270.80</earning>
  </record><record id="4">
    <date>12-03-2016</date>
    <impression>534987</impression>
    <clicks>43</clicks>
    <earning>454.80</earning>
  </record></record>
```

Comment: which writer  you are using?

Comment: I'm using StaxEventItemWriter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [JIRA Ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1835), the issue is not fixed yet in spring batch. However there is work around for this.

**Add maven dependency.**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.stax-utils</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax-utils</artifactId>
    <version>20070216</version>
</dependency>
```

Create a custom class.

```
public class IndentingStaxEventItemWriter <T> extends StaxEventItemWriter<T> {

      private boolean indenting = true;

      @Override
      protected XMLEventWriter createXmlEventWriter( XMLOutputFactory outputFactory, Writer writer) throws XMLStreamException {
        if (indenting) {
          return new IndentingXMLEventWriter( super.createXmlEventWriter( outputFactory, writer ) );
        }
        else {
          return super.createXmlEventWriter( outputFactory, writer );
        }
      }

    public boolean isIndenting() {
        return indenting;
    }

    public void setIndenting(boolean indenting) {
        this.indenting = indenting;
    }

}
```

Modify your EventWriter

```
<bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="com.kp.IndentingStaxEventItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:outputs/report.xml" />
    <property name="encoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
    <property name="version" value="1.0" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="reportMarshaller" />
    <property name="rootTagName" value="record" />
    <!-- TRUE means, that output file will be overwritten if exists - default is TRUE -->
    <property name="overwriteOutput" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: It should get resolved transitively, if check your maven why its not getting resolved(if you are behind proxy, and company level repo). Alternatively you can add that dependency. stax-utils one dependency. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.stax-utils/stax-utils/20070216

Comment: Look at this https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2113 you can replace the content of IndentingStaxEventItemWriter class  with this one https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2113?focusedCommentId=93739&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-93739 and check